# Cookie expiration is browser specific or server specific?

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am setting a a cookie with an expiration time by

```
mktime(24,0,0).
```

My question is simple. If browsers timezone is different , will cookie follow the server's timezone to expire or browser's timezone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Set-Cookie` header has timezone information as part of the expires datetime so the user agent knows when it should expire.

`Set-Cookie: sessionToken=abc123; Expires=Wed, 09 Jun 2021 10:18:14 GMT`

From the php docs for [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> **expire**
>
> ...
>
> Note: You may notice the expire parameter takes on a Unix timestamp,
>   as opposed to the date format Wdy, DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT, this is
>   because PHP does this conversion internally.

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php), *mktime* function :

> Returns the Unix timestamp corresponding to the arguments given. This
>   timestamp is a long integer **containing the number of seconds** between
>   the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and the time specified.

It contains a number of second, a quantity of time : there is no need to care about timezone.

Comment: All you say is true, but it doesn't fully answer the question. The fact that you specify an TTL doesn't mean that PHP translates this correctly. In the end, the browser stores and expires the cookie, and it doesn't store that it needs to delete it 'after 24 hours'.

Comment: setcookie(AboutVisit, date("F jS - g:i a"), mktime(24,0,0)); basically it is active until next day 00:00:00 server side time .?

Answer (score 0):

mktime(24,0,0)

Calculates the unix timestamp of next day 00:00:00 based on the timezone() server machine you are running and returns the integer timestamp.

Now,when you pass that in the 
`setcookie(Visit, date("F jS - g:i a"), mktime(24,0,0));`
On the browser, it converts this 'timestamp since epoch' to the local time zone and sets the expiration for the cookie.

You should be knowing we are here still controlling the cookie lifespan based on the server side time frame.